# Change background color of Reorder icon in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my UITableView: My cell is yellow, but the re-order icon is white :(

[image: yellow row with white reorder icon]

Any quick fix for this? Preferably without having to subclass UITableView or hacking to much.

BTW, this desperate attempt has no effect:

```
cell.backgroundColor =
   cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor =
   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor myNiceYellowColor];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use - `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor myNiceYellowColor];` instead change the complete cell color in datasource method `-tableView:willDisplayCell: forRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have a couple of other tableviewcontrollers to update too :)